# mysql FOUND_ROWS() return wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, php-5.3

I'm trying to use FOUND_ROWS() in my query, but the function returns wrong values sometimes.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS adminslog.*, admins.fullName FROM adminslog 
JOIN admins ON admins.id=adminslog.userId ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

In this query, I get the right value for some, but in others the limit has the wrong value.

```
LIMIT 0,12        164rows        right
LIMIT 12,12       164rows        right
LIMIT 36,12       164rows        right
LIMIT 48,12       164rows        right
LIMIT 50,12       60rows         wrong
LIMIT 62,12       60rows         wrong
```

**Here is my class construct:**

```
class list_table
{
public $number,$page_number,$all_rec,$table_rows,$query_str,$query,$fetch,$table,$db,$fields,$i=0,$page_n,$onclick;

function __construct($query_str,$fields,$page_n,$onclick,$page_number,$number,$db)
{
    $this->fields = $fields; $this->page_number = (((int)$page_number<1)?1:(int)$page_number); $this->number = (int)$number; $this->db = $db;
    $this->i = $this->page_number*$this->number-$this->number; $this->page_n = $page_n; $this->onclick = $onclick;
    $this->query_str = substr(trim($query_str),0,7)."SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".substr(trim($query_str),7)." LIMIT ".(($this->page_number*$this->number)-$this->number).",".$this->number;

    $this->query = $this->db->query($this->query_str);
    $this->table_rows = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();

    $this->all_rec = $this->query->rowCount();
    $this->fetch = $this->query->fetch();

    //$this->table_rows = $this->table_rows->fetch();
    //$this->table_rows = $this->table_rows['cnt'];
    print $this->table_rows;
}

other functions...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question: you think your first `FOUND_ROWS()` is right every time in every query?

check that,if that is true you can run this code only in first query and save it to session.

```
if($this->page_number==1) $_SESSION['cr'] = $this->table_rows = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
```

in this way you have not to check row counts every time.

Comment: yes, you'r right, the first attempt is always correct. but can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

A mysql bug can be responsible for this issue, depending on which version you use:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1468

You can workaround it by using a GROUP BY clause in your query.